# Which languages does android speech recognition support

Tags: android, speech-recognition

I want to implement search using speech recognition, but didn't see information about languages supported by speech recognition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the languages supported by Google Voice Search (which is part of Google App), see [Wikipedia: Google Voice Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Voice_Search). Google Voice Search is the main provider of speech recognition on Android phones, but since the API via which speech recognition is provided on Android is open to everybody, you might be able to find an app that covers a different set of languages.